# How to activate a solution in SharePoint 2010 using client object model?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Here's the situation:

1. I have a customized SharePoint2010 site created.
2. I saved that site as a site template, which has created a solution.
3. I want to be able to activate that solution using SharePoint2010 client object model.

Is that possible? If yes, could you show me how to do it? If no, then could you show me how it can be done using standard SharePoint object model, or any other method?

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score -2):

Can look at an example [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/09/activate-feature-with-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: this links to how to activate a feature, not a solution